# Django 1.7 - Serving static files

Tags: python, django, static, serving

I'm following the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) in order to serve static files but I'm recieving error 404 in the development console. I'm using 'django.contrib.staticfiles', so static files should be automatically served. This is my setup:

Settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Template header:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/app.css" %}">
```

Directory tree:

```
django_project
    \apps
    \static
        \css
            app.css
    \templates
        index.html
```

I can see in firefox console that the path to my file is correct:

[image]

So the problem must be that Django is not serving static files. I can't find what I'm missing. Any advice is more than welcome.

Comment: I think the code has a typo : `"{% static "css/app.css" %}"` , you should replace one pair of double quotes with single quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
I was missing this line in my settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static'),)
```

It looks it's mandatory, same as TEMPLATE_DIRS.

Comment: I also tried to use STATIC_ROOT, but it's deprecated in this version of Django, so only STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS and DEBUG=True need only.

Answer (score 0):

When you run collectstatic it puts all your static content in the path specified by STATIC_ROOT. Check the [deploy to production docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production)

If you are using the django server try checking the path that is being generated by {% static %}...you may have some trailing slash or something missing.

Check that you have are [following all the requirements](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). You need to have django.contrib.staticfiles in your installed apps and something like this in your main urls file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work :)

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project', "static"),
)
```

example of context_processors from settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)
```

example of installed apps in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Actually the only things that you need to serve static files in 1.7 are STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS and 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in your settings. Then you only need to use any static file in your template like {% static "css/app.css" %}. So you don't need to explicitly serve static files in urls.py like in previous versions, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running django-cms and experiencing 404 errors (particularly, all of your static files are having "en-us" prepended to the URL), I found the following steps to help.

First, turn off internationalization of pattern matching in your urls.py file, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960057):

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
      url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

should instead be:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

The import is important, because the configuration of django-cms removes the `patterns` import from `django.conf.urls`.

This solved the redirect, but it still wasn't finding my static files. I needed to manually add the static url to the url patterns, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

After that, static files worked as expected.

I'm sure that this is probably related to me messing up my configuration as a complete novice to Django. But since others might have the same problems, I'm putting it out there as a possible, if less than ideal, solution.