# How to remove language from the address?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Please help me to solve this problem.

I installed Django-cms, I plan to do a monolingual site. When installing I still need to enter a language code. I introduced the RU.

The problem is that when loading any page it adds the following to the web address

```
/ru/
```

I need an address which isn't in the language code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original answer from @ppetrid in [How to remove the language identifier from django-cms 2.4 URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959941/how-to-remove-the-language-identifier-from-django-cms-2-4-urls)

I know `django-cms` is already 3.x version but it should work,

replace this pattern registration:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

with this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```