# multilingual django cms site: seo friendlier home pages (redirects)

Tags: django, redirect, django-cms, multilingual

**NOTE / EDIT: As I've learnt, the default behaviour is ok SEO wise (one redirect is allowed...multiple is no good). So this is a bit of an overkill.**

If my django-cms site is multilingual, visiting `domain.com` always redirects to `domain.com/default-language/`.

Is there a preferred way/package to make this behaviour go away?

Reason I want it are mainly because of SEO. Best solution would be:
`domain.com` => no redirect
`domain.com/default-lang/` => redirect back to `domain.com`
`domain.com/other-lang/` => stay as is, as there is translated content

Example: <del>`http://www.parkhotel-bellevue.ch/` redirects to `http://www.parkhotel-bellevue.ch/de/`, which is what I dont want.</del> http://www.parkhotel-bellevue.ch does it correctly, now.

NOTE: this question is about django-cms, not django alone.

Comment: if you want to remove the multilingual identifiers in the url and want to use it only single langauge refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959941/how-to-remove-the-language-identifier-from-django-cms-2-4-urls)

Comment: my site is multilingual. it only concerns the home page, ie http://domain.com/ without any more slug/address parts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you put your `Index` url in root conf, and all your other pages under `i18n_patterns` ?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

This way, your root URL won't redirect to language specific URL.

For the second part of your question, you could try the following solutions:

- If you have a limited, fixed set of languages, you can hardcode the redirects on your webserver conf (or in your django urls).
- If you don't want to hardcode these redirects, maybe including your `Index` view in your `i18n_patterns` as well could do the trick

Something like:

```
# views.py
class Index(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.path != '/':
            return redirect('/')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

EDIT:

Another option could be to use your own `LocaleMiddleware` by subclassing the one from django.
The redirection part seems to happen here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/locale.py#L29

Comment: I can either put cms.urls in i18n_patterns or not: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html#url-configuration . what I wonder: Is the redirect django made, or is it a "feature" of django-cms?

Comment: I think the redirect is django-made. The behaviour seems to be: when a URL is requested and is not prefixed with a language code,
we redirect to the same URL with a language code.

Comment: thx! subclassing djangos LocaleMiddleware must be it. Will let you know when it works!

Comment: after subclassing LocaleMiddleware and handling redirects there, there were still some gotchas. for example rendering the home page with default language, using the standard cms details view. but was easy ;-) your answer did not fully answer my question, but definitely pushed me in the right direction!